# How to make buttons add a specific text into listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make an app that has a listview and a Horizontal Scroll View above it, with some buttons. 
So far so good, but how do I make the buttons clickable so that when one is pressed, for example button "Test", the text "Test" is added to the listview?

I only know how to do this with a Text Input area, so I'm a litte lost.

Basically, on each button pressed, its own text is added to the listview.

Comment: Do you have code for the listview and its array adapter?

Comment: A button is always clickable if you do not disable it. You can button.setOnClickListener () to implement the code that will be executed when it is pressed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

  final List<String> listViewElements = new ArrayList<String>();
  final ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      listViewElements);

  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Button button = (Button)v;
      String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
      listViewElements.add(buttonText);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  });
}
```

You just have to add a click listener to the button.  In the `onClick` method you add the entry you want to the adapter's ArrayList, and call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to reload the list view.  This code assumes the entries in your adapter are strings, and adds the text of the button that was clicked to the adapter's list of items.

Comment: It works! Thank you, could you just explain what exactly is the "layout.simple_list_item_1" layout?

Comment: Oh just an example for the layout of the rows of the list view